# Eliminate the maximum element from every sublist of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Can anyone help me write a function that eliminates the maximum element from every sublist of a list? I have no ideas...
So far I only know how to write the delete clause:

```
delete(_,[],[]).
delete(E,[H|T],L):-
    delete(E,T,L).
delete(E,[H|T],[H|T1):-
    delete(E,T,T1).
```

For the list `[1,[2,4,3,4],5,[6,7]] ==> [1,[2,3],5,[6]]`

Comment: Do you need to handle more than one level of sublist, like `[1,[2,4,3,[7,1]],5,[[6],[7,8]]]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(_,[],[]).
filter(X,[X|T],L) :- filter(X,T,L).
filter(X,[H|T],L) :- X \= H, filter(X,T,C), append([H],C,L).

removemax([],[]).                              
removemax(X,Y) :- max_list(X,M), filter(M,X,Y).

deletemax([],[]).
deletemax([H|T],X) :- removemax(H,HH), deletemax(T,XX), append([HH],XX,X).
deletemax([H|T],X) :- \+ list(H), deletemax(T,XX), append([H],XX,X).


| ?- deletemax([1,[2,4,3,4],5,[6,7]],X).

X = [1,[2,3],5,[6]] ? ;
```

Comment: Your 3rd `filter/3` predicate reduces to: `filter(X, [H|T], [H|C]) :- X \= H, filter(X, T, C).` Similarly for your second and third `deletemax/2` clauses. You don't need to use `append/3` when the first parameter is a single-element list.

Comment: This is a nice solution (+1) but it doesn't handle all cases of nested sublists (e.g., fails on `[[[1,2],2],[2,4,3,4],5,[6,7]]`). But it's unclear whether the OP needs arbitrary sublist nesting.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for arbitrarily nested sublists. It might, in that regard, be overkill, but the requirement is unclear.

```
% second list is the first list with sublists removed
remove_sublists([H|T], L) :-
    (   is_list(H)
    ->  L = T1
    ;   L = [H|T1]
    ),
    remove_sublists(T, T1).
remove_sublists([], []).

% max value in list ignoring sublists
% if L members are all lists, then this predicate fails
mymax(L, Max) :-
    remove_sublists(L, F),
    F \= [],
    max_list(F, Max).

% delete maximum value from every sublist,
% and sublists of sublists
delete_max_subs([H|T], [H1|T1]) :-
    (   is_list(H)
    ->  (   mymax(H, M)
        ->  delete(H, M, HD)
        ;   HD = H
        ),
        delete_max_subs(HD, H1)
    ;   H1 = H
    ),
    delete_max_subs(T, T1).
delete_max_subs([], []).
```

Some results:

```
| ?- delete_max_subs([1,[2,4,3,4],5,[6,7]], L).

L = [1,[2,3],5,[6]]

yes
| ?- delete_max_subs([[[1,2],2],[2,4,3,4],5,[6,7]], L).

L = [[[1]],[2,3],5,[6]]

yes
| ?- delete_max_subs([[[1,2,3],2,5],[2,4,3,4],5,[6,8,7]], L).

L = [[[1,2],2],[2,3],5,[6,7]]

yes
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

A more Visual/Turbo Prolog friendly version:

```
% second list is the first list with sublists removed
remove_sublists([H|T], T1) :-
    list(H),
    remove_sublists(T, T1).
remove_sublists([H|T], [H|T1]) :-
    not(list(H)),
    remove_sublists(T, T1).
remove_sublists([], []).

% max value in list ignoring sublists
mymax(L, Max) :-
    remove_sublists(L, F),
    F \= [],
    max_list(F, Max).    % I don't know if something like this exists in TP

% delete max recursively from L and all sublists
delete_max(L, R) :-
    mymax(L, M),
    delete(L, M, L1),
    delete_max_subs(L1, R).
delete_max(L, R) :-
    delete_max_subs(L, R).
delete_max([], []).

% delete maximum only from sublists
delete_max_subs([H|T], [H1|T1]) :-
    list(H),
    delete_max(H, H1),
    delete_max_subs(T, T1).
delete_max_subs([H|T], [H|T1]) :-
    not(list(H)),
    delete_max_subs(T, T1).
delete_max_subs([], []).
```

Comment: hi mbratch. Do you know if turbo-prolog has (->)/2 ?

Comment: @CapelliC I couldn't find any evidence that Turbo Prolog supports `(->)/2` so I added a version which doesn't use it.

Comment: really nice! we can appreciate how useful (->)/2 can be!

Comment: @CapelliC I agree. `(->)/2` cleans things up a bit and, in my opinion, elucidates the logic in many cases (when used correctly, of course :)).